# how to get beaglebone black wifi with buildroot

Tags: buildroot

I am trying to build beaglebone black wifi with buildroot but it seems that there are several configuration , for u-boot and kernel.

What is the right def config  , am335-evm or omap3-beagle for BBB wireless?
What is the right kernel and def config for BBB wireless?
U-boot should be the target image format u-boot.bin or u-boot.img?
Does anyone has a git repo of a working beaglebone black ( wireless or not) working?

What are the minimum uEnv.txt settings to get u-boot start working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `beaglebone_defconfig` configuration file:

```
make beaglebone_defconfig
```

It enables support for multiple am335x boards like BBB, am335x-evm etc. This BR configuration provides U-Boot and U-Boot's internal scripts would read the board ID and load corresponding device tree blob. At the end of the build process you'll get a SD card image, that you can directly burn onto your SD card.

The only things missing are WiLink firmware and wpa_supplicant. Just select following packages in BR's menuconfig:

- `BR2_PACKAGE_WILINK_BT_FIRMWARE`
- `BR2_PACKAGE_WPA_SUPPLICANT`

Comment: I of course did tried it in the first time. but it does not work for me ( I pressed the S2 button before plug in 5v power ) but it did not boot. did you tried it?

Comment: @user1820451 you're right. U-Boot doesn't start Linux from SD card. Could you  send an e-mail to the BR's mailing list describing your boot issue? Thanks

Comment: I found too many different kernels and i could not determine which is the right one for beaglebone black. also does the uEnv is correct , looks like it missing lots of settings. and many open questions. i did not find even one buildroot config that works yet on bbb.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it does work, but i was waited to see on the HDMI the login.
After I connected UART using this post:
https://codechief.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/beaglebone-black-serial-debug-connection/   ( but i did replace tx and rx) 
Pressed the S2 button i do see the linux prompt.